# content by users is unpublished - How I can make it publish automatically?

Tags: nodes

I am building Drupal 7 site.

I created a content type.
When an administrator is writing new content - it is immediately published.

But when it is authenticated user - the content is not publish automatically and it's unpublished by default.

When I checked the "publishing option" on the content type, the check box of the "Published" is checked.

Why it's suddenly happen? 
Why the content of authenticated users is being unpublished by default?

Comment: Are you using any workflow modules?

Comment: @Randell thansk for your answer. I have rules installed. But I didn't create a specific rule for that.. What can cause this issue?

Comment: with workflow modules, fe. https://drupal.org/project/workbench is meant, what will introduce this behavior .., does the authenticated user has the box checked, when saving the node ? can it be checked ?

Comment: With workflow modules, it is possible that an authenticated user may only change the status of the content to something like "Needs Review", without the "Publish" option. The "Published" checkbox will still be there but will only work for those with the correct permission.